# How to access an element using Android Appium during the time of audio play?

Tags: appium

I am using AndroidDriver(Appium) for Android Automation and my current app is related to Music composer and beat mixer.
I am stuck at a place where I need to click on an element(beat mixer button).

> Functionality of application is Beat mixer button only gets enabled during the time audio is playing. Before & After of audio play button remains disabled
>
> > Problem is Android Appium waits till the audio play gets completed. Is there any way to click on the beat mixer button during the time audio is playing?

I have tried with the following ways but didn't get any result.

> 1. performMultiTouchAction()
> 2. runAppInBackground(2)

As I need to test on multiple android devices any valuable solution other than coordinates click will be appreciated.

Comment: What is issue you are not able to access element locator ?

Comment: No, I got the element locator, issue is I am not able to click on element when audio is playing, regarding the element state, element remains in disabled state when audio is not playing and if audio is playing then element gets enabled but Appium waits for the audio to get completely played.